# Installing Odoo 9 on CentOS 6.5

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, odoo, centos6, odoo-9

Anyone come across any of the errors below when trying to install Odoo 9 on a CentOS 6.5 2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64 system?

```
Error: Package: odoo-9.0c_20160415-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
       Requires: nodejs-clean-css
Error: Package: odoo-9.0c_20160415-1.noarch (odoo-nightly)
       Requires: python(abi) = 2.7
       Installed: python-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 (@base)
           python(abi) = 2.6

You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I already have python2.7 Installed,
I have v0.10.42 node version installed.

I have epel in the repolist

Any idea what I am missing?

It is said that centOS depends on python2.6 for YUM, I am curious how i can get this yum to point to python2.7 when installing Odoo

```
$ ls -ltr /usr/bin/python*
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 9032 Jul 23  2015 /usr/bin/python2.6
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 9032 Jul 23  2015 /usr/bin/python
-lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    6 Apr 14 19:08 /usr/bin/python2 -> python
$ ls -ltr /usr/local/bin/python*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 6221519 Apr 14 20:22 /usr/local/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    1674 Apr 14 20:25 /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config

$echo $PATH
 /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

It should ideally see python2.7 first, still buffled why it insists on 2.6

Answer (score 0):

Cleared the "(odoo-nightly) Requires: nodejs-clean-css Error: Package: odoo-9.0c_20160415-1.noarch" dependency error with

```
yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/n/nodejs-clean-css-2.2.8-2.el7.noarch.rpm
```

Still cant clear python2.7 dependency error

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
python -V
   #Python 2.7.8
```

Comment: The "alias" is not enough. Check what's in your PATH.

Comment: @DanielReis /usr/local/bin where python2.7 is, is in the path